# Controlling GPS sampling on iPhone

Tags: iphone, gps

I have two questions regarding GPS sampling on iPhone:

1.Is it possible to use CLLocationManager (or any other method) for location readings based on GPS alone without WiFi or Cellular network affecting it?

2.Given a stationary device, is it possible to control the sampling rate? Can I use CLLocationManager to get nonstop location readings from GPS in nanoseconds resolution? If not, what's the best resolution I can get?

Answer (score 0):

regarding number 1, apparently, you cannot directly control gps data.  having said that: if you have speed > 0 AND high accuracy, then you can infer that your data has a high probability of having come from a gps reading.

as far as i know, gps fixing is not measured in nanoseconds, but rather in seconds.  what you mean exactly by resolution (reading frequency?) is a bit unclear.  but, if it is frequency, most navigational software (google, for example) refreshes location every second or so.

hi frequency position updating is very costly in terms of storage cost (server side), query times (server side), battery use (iphone) and heats the phone up bigtime.  i would be going in the opposite direction, especially for stationary devices (sending a heartbeat every 5 minutes or so is usually more than enough).

[reference on CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)